# Axios download from an api on Render stops partially without error thrown

Tags: javascript, rest, axios, web-applications, render

I have a frontend web-app that is making a get request to download a video file from an API backend. The API backend uses a yt-dl wrapper to download a video and send it in the response.

When both the web-app and API are running on localhost, the get request completes with no issue and the video is fully downloaded. I see the progress go all the way to 100%. I can open the video in a media player and watch until the end.

When the API is running on Render, the get request stops as the download reaches 50-80% without throwing an error. I've tried making the get request on postman and on the uploaded webapp but both suffer from the same issue. When I open the video, the first half of the video plays fine, but when I reach the downloaded % of the video (50-80%) It says it uses an unsupported encoding setting.

Interestingly, at some times, the download sometimes goes all the way through without any changes (but this is less common than the partial file download).

Here is the code in my webapp that makes the get request

```js
let url = `${host}/download?v=${videoId}&f=${selectedFormat}&t=${title}`;
try {
    const { data, headers } = await axios.get(url, {
      responseType: "blob",
      onDownloadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
        const progress = (progressEvent.loaded * 1e-6) /
          progressEvent.event.target.getResponseHeader("x-file-size");
        const percent = (Math.round(progress * 1000) / 10.0).toFixed(1);
        console.log("percent complete " + percent + "%");
        // const eta = progressEvent.event.target.getResponseHeader("x-eta");
        // const percent = 100;
        const eta = 1; //not implemented
        updateVideoDownloadProgress(videoId, percent, eta);
      },
    });
    // console.log(headers);
    const blob = new Blob([data], {
      type: `${getFilter(selectedFormat)}/${selectedFormat}`,
    });
    const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    return blobURL;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error; // Rethrow the error to be caught in the calling function
  }
```

Here is the code in my API that sends the video over

```js
app.get("/download", async (req, res) => {
  let { v: videoID, f: format = "mp4", t: title = "default" } = req.query;
  let fileSize = 0;

  try {
    const fileName = `${videoID}.mp4`;
    const url = `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${videoID}`;
    let streamStarted = false;
    let readableStream = ytDlpWrap
      .execStream([url, "-f", "best[ext=mp4]"])
      .on("ytDlpEvent", (eventType, eventData) => {
        if (eventType === "download") {
          const sizeMatch = eventData.match(/([\d.]+)MiB/);
          const eta = eventData.substring(eventData.length - 5);
          console.log(eventData);
          fileSize = sizeMatch ? parseFloat(sizeMatch[1]) : 0;
          if (!streamStarted && fileSize > 0) {
            res.set({ "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "X-File-Size" });
            res.set("X-File-Size", `${fileSize * 1.05}`); // for some reason, the file downloaded is always 5% larger than the file size
            res.set(
              "Content-Disposition",
              `attachment; filename="${title}.${format}"`
            );
            readableStream.pipe(res);
            streamStarted = true;
          }
        }
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(400).json({ message: "Error" });
  }
```

Because my issue is inconsistent, and no errors are thrown, I'm wondering if it is possible for axios requests to be cancelled without error due to slow connection (or maybe I'm not catching the error properly). Any help would be appreciated. I'm new to javascript so I'd love to hear someone else's expertise and comments.